# $elemMatch and $eq equivalent in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a following query for my mongodb. How to translate it to the equivalent code in spring data mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('account').find({
    colorList: {$elemMatch: {
            $eq:"577b"
        }
    }
})
```

one of the account collection is shown as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("133b6ca05e7c058819ab6e6c"),
    "fleetList" : [ 
        "577b",
        "123b"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What type is colorList? String, StringList, ObjectList?

Comment: The "account" collection is shown as above. colorList is the type of String[].

Comment: fleetList or colorList?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$elemMatch` and `$eq`, you can use `$in` for your query too. This query makes exactly that your query does:

```
db.account.find({ "colorList": { $in: ["577b"] } });
```

And for spring-data-mongodb method for this query is:

```
List<Account> findByColorListIn(List<String> colorIds); //In your case colorIds list has one element only.
```

If you want to stick with your query:

```
@Query("{'colorList': {\$elemMatch: {\$eq: ?0}}}")
List<Account> findByColorList(String colorId)
```